# Multi-site - can I route second site to different urls?

Tags: multi-sites, routes

I've got a multi-site Drupal installation with 2 **sub-domains** pointing to the same Drupal site. Eg: **subdomain1.mysite.com** and **subdomain2.mysite.com**

I have a page set up using `hook_menu` with the path `'site/%`'. Eg: ***subdomain1.mysite.com/site/test***

I want all requests to subdomain2.mysite.com/% to point to this page. Eg: subdomain2.mysite.com/test should point to the same page as subdomain1.mysite.com/site/test

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Redirecting to a different domain**

Redirect URLs From Old To New Domain Using 301 Redirects In **.htaccess**

When you need to switch a website from an old domain to a new domain, you need to  redirect all your page URLs, this is when **htaccess** is your friend.

The code below will create 301 url redirects for both the **www** and **non-www** version of ‘**olddomain.com**‘ to the new domain  ‘**newdomain.com**‘.

Add this **.htaccess** file to the OLD site **webroot** and upload the files from the old site to the new to see a seamless switch from an old domain to a new one.

So the example below is redirecting all URLs from **olddomain.com** to **newdomain.com**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.olddomain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^olddomain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You can also apply this to a subdomain – so the example below is redirecting all URLs from **subdomain.olddomain.com** to **subdomain.newdomain.com**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.olddomain.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.subdomain.olddomain.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

For more [details](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/redirecting-a-web-folder-directory-to-another-in-htaccess/)